# Where is the error that is not allowing account #7267881 to be valid

Tags: java

7267881 is in my file as an account and after the file is scanned if you do

```
            System.out.println(Account[2][1]);
```

it prints back 7267881, but when prompted if the user enters 7267881  it returns that it is an invalid number... all the other account numbers in the file work just not this one... why?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AcccountArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Scan the file and save account details to array
        File file = new File ("customers.txt");
        System.out.println("Path : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("customers.txt"));
            String[][] Account = new String[Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())][3];

                    for(int i=0;i<Account.length;i++)
                    {
                        Account[i][0]=scanner.nextLine();
                        Account[i][1]=scanner.nextLine();
                        Account[i][2]=scanner.nextLine();
                    }
                    scanner.close();
                    System.out.println(Account[2][1]);
                Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter account number: ");
                String accountNumber = userinput.next();
                int matchindex = 0;
                Boolean match = false;


                for (int k =0;k<Account.length;k++)
                {
                    if(Account[k][1].equals(accountNumber))
                    {
                        match = true;
                        matchindex = k;
                    }
                }


                if(match)
                {
                    Account ac =  new Account();
                    ac.toString(Account[matchindex][0], Account[matchindex][1], Account[matchindex][2]);
                    System.out.println("Enter 'D' for deposite\nEnter 'W' for withdrawal\nEnter 'Q' for quit");

                    Scanner transaction = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String type = transaction.next();

                    Scanner ammount = new Scanner(System.in);
                    switch (type) {
                    case "D":
                        System.out.println("Enter the ammount : ");
                        float diposit = ammount.nextFloat();
                        float curent = Float.valueOf(Account[matchindex][2]);
                        System.out.println("New balance = "+(curent+diposit));
                        break;
                    case "W":
                        System.out.println("Enter the ammount : ");
                        float withdrawal = ammount.nextFloat();
                        float balance = Float.valueOf(Account[matchindex][2]);
                        System.out.println("New balance = "+(balance-withdrawal));
                        break;
                    case "Q":
                        System.out.println("Exit");
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid transaction");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid user account number");
                }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

the file looks like

```
4
John Anderson
4565413
250.00
Louise Carter 
2323472
1250.45 
Paul Johnson
7267881 
942.81
Sarah Wilson  
0982377
311.26
```

Comment: Voted to close, as you have asked the very same qustion before, but didn't follow the advice you got. Clean up this spaghetti code mess, or use a debugger.

Comment: I asked for clarification on this issue, I really truly do not understand where the problem is, it is the last problem in my code PLEASE help

Comment: I have run a debugger it did nothing

Comment: I know it is bad, I have been coding less than a month, but I am trying to learn and get better did people refuse to help you when you started?

Comment: No  ... but then, I didn't ignore their advice. Which is what you do.

Comment: Im really not trying to ignore advice, I dont undertstand where the problem is and the advice did not make sense to me, I see no compilation problems anymore, the debugger comes up with nothing, every other account and function works except this one number

Comment: For your debugger, make sure to set a breakpoint.

Comment: The debugger "comes up with nothing"? Honestly, do you have the slightest idea what a debugger is supposed to do and how to work with it?

Comment: nope!! which is why I am asking help!!!!!

Comment: You should change your Account class to be more functional.  From your other post, it has a `toString()` method that is... ugly.  `toString()` is a well defined method of creating a string that says something about a class, it's not just a way to hold some `System.out.println` statements.  Your `Account` class should take the three `String`s (name, account, balance) in its constructor and then create a representation of them in its `toString()` method and return that representation.  Then whoever calls `toString()` might print that out if they wanted to.

Comment: @Ingo is overly abusive of you and could instead take this opportunity to help someone in need.  Your code could be cleaned up substantially.  You obviously have a lot to learn about coding in general and object oriented coding in particular.  You could also benefit from paying a little more attention and putting forth a little more effort when people are trying to help.

Comment: @DavidMays He was told all that before, especially to make a working and testable Account class. The problem is that he wants to get away with that code. (And, he finally succeeded!) If you call me abusive then the right term for OPs behaviour is probably barefaced. Please look at my record, and then come back and tell me I am not willing to help when I can. Also, please take into consideration that I could be of the opinion that one helps such people more if one gets them a) to write better code b) learn to use a debugger. You may disagree, but it's still my opinion.

Comment: The Account class was totally irrelevant to the issue. I actually deleted it out all references to it, along with most of the code, so that I could see the code that affected the match decision.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate error is arguably in your input file. There appears to be a space after the account number in question. You need to either make the account number in the file **exactly** as it will be typed during the probe, or trim the strings on input.

However, you do need to learn how to debug effectively. I have some advice on how to do it, with a worked example in Java, at [Debug Strategy](http://patriciashanahan.com/debug/index.html).

Comment: Much more constructive than the other abuse being heaped at the poster

Comment: +1, but sad thing is that he now has learned that he can write the most absurd code and still get help. He will just fix the monstrosity above and will carry on the same way .....